# Save dynamic div into SESSION

Tags: php

Hello guys i have the following PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_slider']))
    {
        echo '<div class="sliderz">';
        $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store");               
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) 
            {
                echo '<ul class="connectedSortable">';
                echo '<li>';
                echo "<img class='ui-state-default' src=".$row['image'].">";
                echo '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

and the html looks like this:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add new slider!" name='add_slider'>
                </form>
```

How can i acciev the same thing but save it into $_SESSION :-?

Comment: What exactly do you want to save to the `$_SESSION`? The html or the rows from the `store` table?

Comment: i would like to save the whole div + content

Comment: I think you should use variable instead of echo (ex $content .= '<div class="sliderz">' or get content by using ob_start(), ob_get_contents()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['add_slider']))
{
    $output = '<div class="sliderz">';
    $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store");               
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) 
        {
            $output .= '<ul class="connectedSortable">';
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= "<img class='ui-state-default' src=".$row['image'].">";
            $output .= '</li>';
            $output .= '</ul>';
        }
    $output .= '</div>';

   $_SESSION['yourKey'] = $output;
}
```

this will store the `div` as a string in `$_SESSION` array with `yourKey` as a key

when you need that just do

```
echo $_SEESION['yourKey'];
```

also dont forget to start your session with `session_start();` or else it will give errors.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add_slider']))
        {
            $arr = array(); //the array will hold the html element 
            $arr[] = '<div class="sliderz">';
            $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store");               
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) 
                {

                $arr[] = '<ul class="connectedSortable">';
            $arr[] = '<li>';
                    $arr[] = "<img class='ui-state-default' src=".$row['image'].">";
                    $arr[] = '</li>';
                    $arr[] = '</ul>';
                }
            $arr[] = '</div>';

            $_SESSION['your_session'] = implode("",$arr); // the array content will be gluedd together to form a your div with contents inside it
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `serialize` instead of `implode`